# Cakephp paginator jump with multiple pages

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0, paginator

I use cakephp 3.x paginator and I have a request from customer.

Example:

- My paginate bar, now it's stand at #1.

`<< | < | **1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | > | >>`

- When I click to ">>" the bar will show 10-19 and stand at #10

`<< | < | **10** 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 | > | >>`

- Click to ">>" again, it will show 20-29 and stand at #20

`<< | < | **20** 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 | > | >>`

- Same with "<<", will back to 10-19 and 1-9.

---

The ">" and "<" just go next page and back to prev page.

So my question is:

- How can I make the ">>" and "<<" button with cakephp pagination helper?

My code in view.ctp is

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Paginator->first(<<);

  echo $this->Paginator->prev('<');

  echo $this->Paginator->numbers();

  echo $this->Paginator->next('>');

  echo $this->Paginator->last(>>);
?>
```

Comment: Use single/double quotes with `<<` and `>>`... `first('<<')`, `last('>>')`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your meaning.

Comment: Replace this `echo $this->Paginator->first(<<);` with this `echo $this->Paginator->first('<<');` and same with the `last`

Comment: Sorry but it does not suitable with my request. When I click >> it will move to the end of pages.

Comment: Because `first()` and `last()` stands for first and last page simultaneously

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, try do that but it's not successful, so I ask for other suggestion. Please consider to the request not my source code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built-in paginator helper method that would create such links, you may want to [**file a feature request**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) for that, I think it would be a nice addition.

That being said, you can build such jump links manually, the paginator helper offers everything that is needed, that is, the current page number, a method to check whether a given page exists, and functionality for generating links from the helpers templates.

Here's a basic example, this would generate a jump link for the current page + 10 in case that page exists:

```
$page = $this->Paginator->current() + 10;
if ($this->Paginator->hasPage($page)) {
    echo $this->Paginator->templater()->format('nextActive', [
        'url' => $this->Paginator->generateUrl(['page' => $page]),
        'text' => '>>',
    ]);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > Checking the Pagination State](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#checking-the-pagination-state)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > Template Names](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#template-names)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::current()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Helper.PaginatorHelper.html#_current)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::hasPage()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Helper.PaginatorHelper.html#_hasPage)**

[Templater docs are currently missing](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-api-docs/issues/75) for some reason...